# Get Specific JSON Object based on TextView

Tags: android, json

I am a newbie in android developers and
I need help to get a specific object based on a text on TextView and show it on another TextView.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
    "card_data": [{
        "card_id": "123456",
        "balance": "100000"
    }, {
        "card_id": "654321",
        "balance": "50000"
    }]
}
```

For example on my `TextView1` I have "123456".

How can I display "100000" on `TextView2`?

Comment: code will be something like this 'TextView1.setText(array.Index(0).value)};TextView2.setText(array.Index(1).value);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create setter and getter for your json. See below code.

```
private class CardInfo
{
    private String cardId;
    private String balance;

    public CardInfo(String cardId, String balance) {
        this.cardId = cardId;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getCardId() {
        return cardId;
    }

    public String getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Then create JsonParser for your Json Object and add json obj as a CardInfoObj in ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<CardInfo> mList = new ArrayList<>();
private void jsonParser()
{

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\n" +
                "\t\"card_data\": [{\n" +
                "\t\t\"card_id\": \"123456\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"balance\": \"100000\"\n" +
                "\t}, {\n" +
                "\t\t\"card_id\": \"654321\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"balance\": \"50000\"\n" +
                "\t}]\n" +
                "}");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("card_data");
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject user = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            mList.add(new CardInfo(user.get("card_id").toString(), user.get("balance").toString()));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now In mList having cardId and balance for each json obj. now get cardinfo obj from mList.

```
private void setText()
{
    CardInfo cardInfo = mList.get(0);// get specfice obj based on your requirement.
    mTvCard.setText(cardInfo.getCardId());
    mTvBalance.setText(cardInfo.getBalance());
}
```

Comment: what if I've already string my json url as String json_url = "myurl" , 
based on your code, is it still working,
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_url);

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your code, its really help, I would like to upvote but I don't have enough reputation for that, but if i'm not wrong, your code will parsing both data "card_id" and "balance" , 
my purpose is my "card_id" which is (mTVCard) are getting text from nfc tag, so when mTvCard is "123456" mTvBalance will be "100000" | when mTvCard is "654321" mTv Balance will be "50000",
Thanks.

Comment: I already accept your answer, can you help me again with my case above?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the data type of json field. If balance is Integer type      then extract integer from json and convert it to string type using String.valueOf("100000"). Now you can set the value on textfield.